# How to open up another tab with a different shell in console2

Tags: console2

In my console2 settings under tabs, I have 3 different tabs the defult console, one with powershell shell and one with bash shell.

Is there a way to set a hotkey so when I press ex, `ctrl + a` it opens up powershell and `ctrl + b` it opens up bash?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) which is a fork of Console2. So the setting is possibly the same, if not you might consider using ConsoleZ instead.

You can define hotkeys for **New tab 1** to **New tab 12** in the settings. By default the hotkeys to open new tabs are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and to switch existing tabs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>